# Failed to applying css via express/node

Tags: express

i am trying to finding a way of simply integrated my static front-end file with node/express. I don't know if i am right:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

Within the index.html file my CSS was included with the path: `href= "public/css/style.css"`.

But it throws the error, `because its MIME type ('text/html')` and I have checked few answers on the stack just couldn't really understand that. I hope someone could answer my questions which are:

1. Do I have to use any templated engines like Jade when working on HTML file with node?
2. I just want to build a server with express and set home page to index.html, but why I can't apply the CSS there? Do I need to set a middleware there?

Comment: import your css file insde index.html file

Comment: I am using the sass for styling and compiling it to the public/css/style.css, is there any other way to integration my sass/css styling instead of wrapping them all in a same file?